# How to implement algorithm for converting "month-week-day-hour" to "day of year"?

Tags: c, algorithm, time

```
enum months
{
    JAN = 1, FEB, MAR, APR, MAY, JUN, JUL, AUG, SEP, OCT, NOV, DEC
};

enum weeks
{
    first = 1, second, third, fourth, last
};

enum days
{
    sun = 1, mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat
};

enum hours
{
    zero = 1, one, two ..., twenty-three = 24
};

enum months month = get_month();

enum weeks week = get_week();

enum days day = get_day();

enum hours hour = get_hour();

uint16_t day_of_year = days_since_jan_1(month, week, day, hour);
```

How to implement *days_since_jan_1* ?

Comment: There are many way to do it, where is exactly your problem?

Comment: Are we to assume that the first day of the year is always a Sunday?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.  StackOverflow is not a homework service.

Comment: If i understand your input format correctly, there are essentially 3 problems that need to be solved here: 1. leap years, 2: determine what day the 1st of january actually is for the given year and 3: dealing with the weeks of the month (because a month often doesn't start on a sunday, but in the middle of a week)

Comment: You also need to know if it is a leap year

Comment: The best way to solve problems like this is to think of how you would solve it on paper, by hand. Once you've figured out how to do it by hand, write a program to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

as already mentioned, you need the year to do this calculation in order to decide, how many days you need to count for February.

I tried to tackle the problem using the following code snippet using [Zeller's Congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence) as it's independent of date / time functions. I tried to add some comments what I do where and why, I also did some tests and it seems to work, but there may be some edge / corner cases I didn't think of. I'm pretty sure that it's not the optimal solution, feel free to give feedback.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// defines the day offsets of each month in "normal" and "leap" year
static const int days_of_months[2][13] = {
    {0, 0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334},
    {0, 0, 31, 60, 91, 121, 152, 182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335}
};

/* 
    Leap year is defined as: 
        * divisable by 4 except divisable by 100 OR
        * divisable by 400
*/
int year_is_leap(int year)
{
    return (((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0));
}

// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeller%27s_congruence
int get_day_of_the_week(int year, int month, int day)
{
    int h, q, m, K, J = 0; 

    q = day; 
    m = month;

    if (month < 3) 
    {
        m = month + 12;
        year -= 1;
    } 

    K = year % 100;
    J = year / 100;

    h = (q + (13*(m+1))/5 + K + K/4 + J/4 + 5*J) % 7;

    // remap to Sunday = 1 ... Saturday = 7
    return ((h+6)%7)+1;
}

int get_days_since_first_jan (int year, int month, int week, int day)
{
    int days_passed = 0, i = 0;

    // if date is in week 1, use given day of week to get the days of this month
    if (week == 1)
    {
        days_passed += day - get_day_of_the_week (year, month, 1) + 1; 
    }
    else 
    {
        //iterate over weeks
        for (i = week; i > 0; i --)
        { 
            // in week one, get the weekday of the first of the month, to get remaining days of this week for this month
            if (i == 1)
            {
                days_passed += 7 - (get_day_of_the_week (year, month, 1) - 1);
            }
            // in the given week, simply add the given days to it
            else if (i == week)
            {
                days_passed += day;
            }
            // for all other weeks, add 7 days
            else 
            {
                days_passed += 7;
            }
        }
    }

    // Add the offset of the given month in days
    days_passed += days_of_months[year_is_leap (year)][month];

    return days_passed;
}

int main(void)
{
    // 2020/1/31 -> 31
    printf("%d\n", get_days_since_first_jan(2020, 1, 5, 6));

    // 2020/2/28 -> 59
    printf("%d\n", get_days_since_first_jan(2020, 2, 5, 6));

    // 2020/4/15 -> 106
    printf("%d\n", get_days_since_first_jan(2020, 4, 3, 4));

    // 2020/8/17 -> 230
    printf("%d\n", get_days_since_first_jan(2020, 8, 4, 2));

    // 2021/3/1 -> 60
    printf("%d\n", get_days_since_first_jan(2021, 3, 1, 2));

    // 2021/3/1 -> 60
    printf("%d\n", get_days_since_first_jan(2021, 3, 1, 2));

    // 2021/3/9 -> 68
    printf("%d\n", get_days_since_first_jan(2021, 3, 2, 3));

    // 2028/1/1 -> 1
    printf("%d\n", get_days_since_first_jan(2028, 1, 1, 7));

    // 2028/8/29 -> 242
    printf("%d\n", get_days_since_first_jan(2028, 8, 5, 3));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if it works and you're happy with it, upvote is highly appreciated! ;)